# Passing variables between nested playbooks

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook where I'm spinning up an instance in aws with the `ec2` module. To be more flexible I ask via prompt for the hostname. I found in the `ec2` examples the code snippet, which allows you to run a second playbook with newly spun up instance for further configuration.

Now I want to set the hostname via module `hostname` but I cannot access the variable in the second playbook.

This is how my playbook looks like:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  ...

  vars_prompt:
    - name: var_hostname
      prompt: "Please enter the hostname"
      private: no

  tasks:

    - name: Spin up instance
      local_action:
        module: ec2
        ...
      register: ec2

    - name: Add new instance to host group
      add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groupname=launched
      with_items: ec2.instances

- hosts: launched
  ...

  tasks:

    - name: Set hostname
      hostname: name="{{ var_hostname }}"
```

> fatal: [launched] => One or more undefined variables: 'var_hostname' is undefined

Is there a way to pass a variable from one playbook to another one?

I found [Ansible best practice for passing vars to nested playbooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077272/ansible-best-practice-for-passing-vars-to-nested-playbooks) but unfortunately it didn't had a solution which I can use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of **[How do I set register a variable to persist between plays in ansible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896847/how-do-i-set-register-a-variable-to-persist-between-plays-in-ansible)**

Comment: In this particular case, it's more efficient to put the variables into the parameters of the module *add_host*.

Answer (score 7):

You can use set_fact and hostvars together to achieve what you want.

Do set_fact on one group of hosts( i.e localhost), and access them in a different play using hostvars

> {{hostvars['localhost']["new_fact"]}}

Comment: This works, a full playbook example in the answer would be most useful.

Comment: A full working example is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896847/how-do-i-set-register-a-variable-to-persist-between-plays-in-ansible

Answer (score 5):

You can use local files.

1) Write

```
- name: write public ip
  local_action:
    template:
      dest: /tmp/ansible_master_public_ip.txt
      src: templates/public_ip.j2
```

2) Retrieve with http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html

```
hostname: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/ansible_master_public_ip.txt') | trim }}"
```

PS. Ini file lookup also an option if you need more than few variables.

Answer (score 0):

- Add the host's variable to the parameters. For example,

```yaml
    - name: Add new instance to host group
      add_host:
        hostname: "{{ ec2.instances.0.public_ip }}"
        groupname: launched
        var_hostname: "{{ var_hostname }}"
```

- See [examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html#examples)
- Use only the first item from the list because you have only one hostname. There is no reason to iterate the list.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_prompt:
    - name: var_hostname
      prompt: "Please enter the hostname"
      private: no
  vars:
    ec2:
      instances:
        - public_ip: AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD
  tasks:
    - name: Add new instance to host group
      add_host:
        hostname: "{{ ec2.instances.0.public_ip }}"
        groupname: launched
        var_hostname: "{{ var_hostname }}"

- hosts: launched
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: var_hostname
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 
Please enter the hostname: host_2

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Add new instance to host group] ********************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY [launched] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD] => 
  var_hostname: host_2

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
localhost      : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

- Use [*pause*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html#ansible-builtin-pause-module-pause-playbook-execution) instead of *vars_prompt* if you have more hosts. For example,

```yaml
    - name: Get var_hostname(s)
      pause:
        prompt: "Please enter the hostname for {{ item.public_ip }}"
        echo: yes
      loop: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
      register: var_hostnames
    - name: Add new instances to host group
      add_host:
        hostname: "{{ item.item.public_ip }}"
        groupname: launched
        var_hostname: "{{ item.user_input }}"
      loop: "{{ var_hostnames.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.user_input }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ec2:
      instances:
        - public_ip: AAA.BBB.CCC.DD1
        - public_ip: AAA.BBB.CCC.DD2
  tasks:
    - name: Get var_hostname(s)
      pause:
        prompt: "Please enter the hostname for {{ item.public_ip }}"
        echo: yes
      loop: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
      register: var_hostnames
    - name: Add new instances to host group
      add_host:
        hostname: "{{ item.item.public_ip }}"
        groupname: launched
        var_hostname: "{{ item.user_input }}"
      loop: "{{ var_hostnames.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.user_input }}"

- hosts: launched
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: var_hostname
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Get var_hostname(s)] *******************************************************************
[Get var_hostname(s)]
Please enter the hostname for AAA.BBB.CCC.DD1:
host_1^Mok: [localhost] => (item={'public_ip': 'AAA.BBB.CCC.DD1'})
[Get var_hostname(s)]
Please enter the hostname for AAA.BBB.CCC.DD2:
host_2^Mok: [localhost] => (item={'public_ip': 'AAA.BBB.CCC.DD2'})

TASK [Add new instances to host group] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=host_1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=host_2)

PLAY [launched] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [AAA.BBB.CCC.DD1] => 
  var_hostname: host_1
ok: [AAA.BBB.CCC.DD2] => 
  var_hostname: host_2

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
AAA.BBB.CCC.DD1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
AAA.BBB.CCC.DD2: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
localhost      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```