# Access variable in other play - Ansible

Tags: ansible

Ansible Version: 2.4.2.0

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896847/how-do-i-set-register-a-variable-to-persist-between-plays-in-ansible) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808649/ansible-accessing-register-variables-from-other-plays-within-same-playbook), I was able write below playbook

```
$ cat test.yml 
- name: Finding Master VMs
  hosts: all-compute-host
  remote_user: heat-admin
  tasks:
  - name: Getting master VM's hostname
    shell: hostname
    register: hostname_output

- name: Access in different play
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: Testing vars
    debug: var='{{ hostvars[item]['hostname_output']['stdout'] }}'
    with_items: groups['all-compute-host']
```

I don't want use `gather_facts: true` and access hostname from it. Getting below error when I try to above playbook

```
-----------OUTPUT REMOVED----------------
TASK [Testing vars] *******************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: u\"hostvars['groups['all-compute-host']']\" is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/tmp/test.yml': line 18, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n  - name: Testing vars\n    ^ here\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: u\"hostvars['groups['all-compute-host']']\" is undefined"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/tmp/test.retry
-----------OUTPUT REMOVED----------------
```

I tried below things

1. `debug: var=hostvars[item]['hostname_output']['stdout']`
2. `debug: var=hostvars.item.hostname_output.stdout'`

I have also tried direct host group instead of iterating `item` like below

1. `debug: var=hostvars.all-compute-host.hostname_output.stdout'`
2. `debug: var=hostvars['all-compute-host']['hostname_output']['stdout']`

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "hostvars['all-compute-host']['hostname_output']['stdout']": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

I have also try direct host name.But no use

1. `debug: var='hostvars.compute01.hostname_output.stdout'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `debug` statement:

```
tasks:
  - name: Testing vars
    debug: var='{{ hostvars[item]['hostname_output']['stdout'] }}'
    with_items: groups['all-compute-host']
```

There are two issues:

- The value of the `var` argument to the `debug` module is evaluated in a Jinja templating context.  That means you **must not** use the `{{...}}` template markers.
- On the hand, the argument to `with_items` **does** need the `{{...}}` markers; without that, you're iterating over a list consisting of a single item, the literal string `groups['all-compute-host']`.

With both of those problems fixed (and a few minor stylistic changes), you get:

```
tasks:
  - name: Testing vars
    debug:
      var: hostvars[item].hostname_output.stdout
    with_items: "{{ groups['all-compute-host'] }}"
```