# How to use return values of one task in another task for a different host in ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I was trying to setup mysql master slave replication with ansible for a hostgroup consisting of 2 mysql hosts.

Here is my scenario:

I run one task in the 1st host and skips the 2nd host, so the 1st task (i.e master replication status) returns some values like Position, File etc.

Then, I run another task in 2nd host (skips the 1st hosts), This task uses the return values of the 1st task like master.Position, master.File etc.

Now, when I run the playbook, the variables of the 1st task does not seem to be working in the 2nd task

**Inventory File**

```
    [mysql]
    stagmysql01 ansible_host=1.1.1.1 ansible_ssh_user=ansible ansible_connection=ssh
    stagmysql02 ansible_host=1.1.1.2 ansible_ssh_user=ansible ansible_connection=ssh
```

**Tasks on Master**

```
- name: Mysql - Check master replication status.
  mysql_replication: mode=getmaster
  register: master

- debug: var=master
```

**Tasks on Slave**

```
- name: Mysql - Configure replication on the slave.
  mysql_replication:
    mode: changemaster
    master_host: "{{ replication_master }}"
    master_user: "{{ replication_user }}"
    master_password: "{{ replication_pass }}"
    master_log_file: "{{ master.File }}"
    master_log_pos: "{{ master.Position }}"
  ignore_errors: True
```

**Master Output**

```
TASK [Mysql_Base : Mysql - Check master replication status.] ****************
skipping: [stagmysql02]
ok: [stagmysql01]

TASK [Mysql_Base : debug] ***************************************************
ok: [stagmysql01] => {
    "master": {
        "Binlog_Do_DB": "", 
        "Binlog_Ignore_DB": "mysql,performance_schema", 
        "Executed_Gtid_Set": "", 
        "File": "mysql-bin.000003", 
        "Is_Master": true, 
        "Position": 64687163, 
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false
    }
}
ok: [stagmysql02] => {
    "master": {
        "changed": false, 
        "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False", 
        "skipped": true
    }
}
```

**Slave Output**

```
TASK [Mysql_Base : Mysql - Configure replication on the slave.] *************
skipping: [stagmysql01]
fatal: [stagmysql02]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'File'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/ansible/roles/Mysql_Base/tasks/replication.yml': line 30, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Mysql - Configure replication on the slave.\n  ^ here\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: 'dict object' has no attribute 'File'"}
...ignoring
```

As, you can see above, the 2nd task failed for 2nd host because of undefined variables. However the required variables are there in 1st task of 1st host.

How do I use the variables returned from 1st host in 2nd host in another task ?

P.S: I have seen the approach of using {{ hostvars['inventory_hostname']['variable'] }}.
However I'm quite confused with this approach as the inventory_hostname or IP address needs to be added directly. I was looking for a common template that can be used for different inventory files and playbooks.

Comment: So what is the question in that case? You set the inventory name and you refer to it in the playbook. Problem solved. It’s not an IP address or a hostname which you might not know in advance.

Comment: If have different environments like , staging, production etc. and I have environment specific inventory files and playbooks, I want to use the same role for all environments. So the tasks in the roles cannot refer a inventory name in particular, as it would be different for other inventory files.

Comment: I’m sorry, but what you wrote makes no sense to me. Ansible was designed exactly to solve this problem by using inventories. Just start with tutorials on docs.ansible.com

Comment: In the question, you can see that I run a task in  the 1st host, skips the 2nd hosts and task returns values for variables like Position, File etc only for 1st host.
I run the another task in the 2nd host, this time 1st host is skipped. 
How to use the variables of 1st host in 2nd host ?

Comment: You have included the proper syntax in the question above. Other concerns constitute an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by defining the variables to a new **dummy host** and then using it across the playbook with *hostvars*.

Similar solution was already mentioned in one of the answers in [How do I set register a variable to persist between plays in ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896847/how-do-i-set-register-a-variable-to-persist-between-plays-in-ansible)
However I did not notice it until I posted this question.

Here is what I did in the ansible tasks:

- I have created a dummy host *master_value_holder* and defined the
  required variables. (Here I needed *master_log_file* and
  *master_log_Postion*)
- Accessed the variables using *hostvars['master_value_holder']['master_log_file']*

**Tasks on Master**

```
- name: Mysql - Check master replication status.
  mysql_replication: mode=getmaster
  register: master

- name: "Add master return values to a dummy host"
  add_host:
    name:   "master_value_holder"
    master_log_file: "{{ master.File }}"
    master_log_pos: "{{ master.Position }}"
```

**Tasks for Slave**

```
- name: Mysql - Displaying master replication status
  debug: msg="Master Bin Log File  is {{ hostvars['master_value_holder']['master_log_file'] }} and Master Bin Log Position is {{ hostvars['master_value_holder']['master_log_pos'] }}"

- name: Mysql - Configure replication on the slave.
  mysql_replication:
    mode: changemaster
    master_host: "{{ replication_master }}"
    master_user: "{{ replication_user }}"
    master_password: "{{ replication_pass }}"
    master_log_file: "{{ hostvars['master_value_holder']['master_log_file'] }}"
    master_log_pos: "{{ hostvars['master_value_holder']['master_log_pos'] }}"
  when: ansible_eth0.ipv4.address != replication_master and not slave.Slave_SQL_Running
```

**Output**

```
TASK [Mysql_Base : Mysql - Check master replication status.] ****************
skipping: [stagmysql02]
ok: [stagmysql01]

TASK [AZ-Mysql_Base : Add master return values to a dummy host] ****************
changed: [stagmysql01]

TASK [AZ-Mysql_Base : Mysql - Displaying master replication status] ************
ok: [stagmysql01] => {
    "msg": "Master Bin Log File  is mysql-bin.000001 and Master Bin Log Position is 154"
}
ok: [stagmysql02] => {
    "msg": "Master Bin Log File  is mysql-bin.000001 and Master Bin Log Position is 154"
}

TASK [AZ-Mysql_Base : Mysql - Configure replication on the slave.] *************
skipping: [stagmysql01]
skipping: [stagmysql02]
```

As you can see from the above output that the master replication status is available for both the hosts now.