# How can I reference a registered variable from one ansible play in another?

Tags: ansible

I need to check if VMs exist or not. The check is registered in one play, 'control' and referenced in another, 'production'.  What is the correct format for this?

create_vm.yml:

```
---
- hosts: control
  tasks:
  - name: Check VM
    virt:
      command: "list_vms"
    register: vms

- hosts: production
  tasks:
  - name: Create VM
  STUFF
  when: inventory_hostname not in groups['control']['vms']
```

I've tried different 'when' formats but they've all failed.

I have various errors depending on the format of when condition used; the following is for the specified condition.

```
fatal: [prod-operator]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'inventory_hostname not in groups['control']['vms']' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (inventory_hostname not in groups['control']['vms']): Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({% if inventory_hostname not in groups['control']['vms'] %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': argument of type 'StrictUndefined' is not iterable\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/micks-ci-setup/production/virtual_machine/create-vm.yml': line 29, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Create Production VM\n    ^ here\n"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set register a variable to persist between plays in ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896847/how-do-i-set-register-a-variable-to-persist-between-plays-in-ansible)

Comment: I checked that and tried various adaptations but did not work for me.  I may of course be overlooking something simple.

Comment: could you please update the question with the actual error you're getting?

Comment: Please see error above.

Comment: Thanks! this error shows which task the problem is --  `- name: Create Production VM`. No surprises there, an argument is undefined and therefore not iterable. It looks like you're just referencing the variable incorrectly. It should be `inventory_hostname not in vms` since `vms` is the name of the variable you're registering. If you're putting  a host into a group, you should use [add_host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html#add-host-module)

Comment: That was my starting point and works for hosts: control as vms is registered there, the issue is when I try to reference in hosts: production. Error for this when condition is in following comment.

Comment: Cut this a little short to fit.

The conditional check 'inventory_hostname not in vms' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (inventory_hostname not in vms): Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({% if inventory_hostname not in vms %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': argument of type 'StrictUndefined' is not iterable\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/micks-ci-setup/production/virtual_machine/create-vm.yml'

Comment: debug show fine in hosts: control but undefined in hosts: production.

    ok: [host01] => {
        "vms": {
            "changed": false,
            "list_vms": []
        }
    }

ok: [prod-operator] => {
    "vms": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

I think it needs to reference control hosts.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen I should be able to reference the registered value form another task using a reference to host but it just won't work for me.  I'll move on with a workaround of performing another check in the hosts: production play as follows.

(I'm doing a round-robin deployment of VMs hence the delegate_to complexity)

```
---
- hosts: control
  tasks:
  - name: Check VM
    virt:
      command: "list_vms"
    register: vms

- hosts: production
  tasks:
  - name: Check VMs
    virt:
      command: "list_vms"
    register: vms
    delegate_to: '{{ groups["control"][play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) % groups["control"]|length] }}'
```

And when condition as follows:

```
when: inventory_hostname not in vms.list_vms
```

If anyone can provide the "correct" method or a reason why it's not working for me then please feel free to post another answer.