# Disable gather_facts for a single host only

Tags: ansible

I am trying to share some variables between multiple hosts in a playbook, and am using the technique described in this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896847/how-do-i-set-register-a-variable-to-persist-between-plays-in-ansible).  It works, however each run ansible complains that the dummy host (K8S_MASTER_CA_HASH) does not exist, so it can't gather facts about it.

Is it possible to tell ansible not to gather facts for a single host in a play run against various hosts?

I tried using 'localhost' as the dummy host to hold the variables, but then ansible complains it can't ssh to localhost.  (Seems like wrong approach)

Comment: You can try the play level `connection` keyword for localhost to prevent Ansible from trying an SSH connection, like `connection: local`.

Comment: using localhost seems to be the wrong approach.  A 'dummy' host as suggested makes most sense, I just can't tell ansible how to not gather facts on that dummy host

Comment: Having a separate play for dummy host with `gather_facts: false`, could be an option in that case.