# Create a "global" list variable in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I need to use a list variable in other task with other hosts:

```
---
- name: open_firewall - IP servers list
  hosts: servers
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Create servers list
      set_fact:
        servers_ip: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']}}"

    - name: Se imprime
      debug:
        var: servers_ip

- name: open_firewall - Open the firewall of wazuh servers
  hosts: wazuh-servers
  tasks:
    - name: Allow port range 1514-1515
      ufw:
        rule: allow
        port: 1514:1515
        proto: tcp
        src: "{{ item }}"
      loop:  
        "{{ servers_ip }}"
```

but I have this error:

```
TASK [Allow port range 1514-1515] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [wazuh.server.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'servers_ip' is undefined"}
```

Can I create a "global" list variable or that is impossible? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33896847/how-do-i-set-register-a-variable-to-persist-between-plays-in-ansible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[servers]
test_11
test_12
test_13

[wazuh_servers]
test_21
test_22
test_23
```

Get the server's facts

```yaml
- hosts: servers
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_all_ipv4_addresses.0
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  ansible_all_ipv4_addresses.0: 10.1.0.61
ok: [test_12] => 
  ansible_all_ipv4_addresses.0: 10.1.0.62
ok: [test_13] => 
  ansible_all_ipv4_addresses.0: 10.1.0.63
```

To create the list of the IPs put the below declaration into the *vars*

```yaml
  servers_ip: "{{ groups.servers|
                  map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_all_ipv4_addresses')|
                  map('first')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  servers_ip:
  - 10.1.0.61
  - 10.1.0.62
  - 10.1.0.63
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: servers
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_all_ipv4_addresses.0

- hosts: wazuh_servers
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    servers_ip: "{{ groups.servers|
                    map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_all_ipv4_addresses')|
                    map('first')|list }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: servers_ip
```

```yaml
PLAY [servers] ********************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************
ok: [test_11]
ok: [test_12]
ok: [test_13]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  ansible_all_ipv4_addresses.0: 10.1.0.61
ok: [test_12] => 
  ansible_all_ipv4_addresses.0: 10.1.0.62
ok: [test_13] => 
  ansible_all_ipv4_addresses.0: 10.1.0.63

PLAY [wazuh_servers] **************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_21] => 
  servers_ip:
  - 10.1.0.61
  - 10.1.0.62
  - 10.1.0.63
ok: [test_22] => 
  servers_ip:
  - 10.1.0.61
  - 10.1.0.62
  - 10.1.0.63
ok: [test_23] => 
  servers_ip:
  - 10.1.0.61
  - 10.1.0.62
  - 10.1.0.63
```

Comment: The problem is also the use of "-" in the group name. Thanks.